# FileNotFoundError with absolute path when trying to read tarball

Tags: python, tarfile

I am trying to read from a tar-file but despite specifying the absolute path
i get a *FileNotFoundError*.

This is the relevant portion of code:

```
1 from pathlib import Path
2
3 testPath = Path("G:/test.tar")
4 tar = tarfile.open(testPath, "r")
5 ...
```

and the file definitely exists.
[image]

But what I get is (originating from line 4):

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'G:\\test.tar'
```

(I am using PyCharm btw.)
What am I missing? I will gladly provide additional information if needed.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this code. Are you sure the file is there and readable by the user the Python is running as?

Comment: It is most definitely there (recognized by explorer and PowerShell as well with non-zero filesize) and I am executing PyCharm as admin.

Comment: Ooohhhh you directed me in the right direction so i could resolve the issue. Windows was cutting of the fact that this is gzipped, which means it is actually test.tar.gz. Which I didn't see due to the fact that there are only folders apart form this file in this particular directory. I just recognized it taking a second look at the powershell. Thanks for the hint! (I feel slightly stupid now.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

after a recent pc-reset I forgot to change explorer-view to "always show file-type-extension" again which led to me not recognizing that it should have been

```
test.tar.gz
```

as there were only other folders in this directory apart from the file in question.
So adjusting my testPath solved that.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure your script/file is located in the correct directory

```
from pathlib import Path
import tarfile

testPath = Path("Songs.txt.tar")
tar = tarfile.open(testPath, "r")
print(tar) # Returns <tarfile.TarFile object at 0x100d44f98>

print(tarfile.is_tarfile("Songs.txt.tar")) # Returns True if its tar file
```

Answer (score 0):

Since in the line number 3 you are generating file path using the following line:

```
testPath = Path("G:/test.tar")
```

testPath variable is of type pathlib.WindowsPath.
while in the next tarfile.open requires filepath in string format.

Please try following:

```
testPath = Path("G:/test.tar")
tar = tarfile.open(str(testPath), "r")
```

or:

```
testPath = str(Path("G:/test.tar"))
tar = tarfile.open(testPath, "r")
```

Comment: There's no need for `str()` here. You can pass a `Path` to `open()` just fine.

Comment: but doing so the error is reported in the execution, if you covert it to str it is working fine. What could be the reason for failure without converting it to str?